# S-10 Truck Problems

Tags: s10

When I'm driving and my foot is off the gas pedal, my truck slows down on its own faster than usual. I recently got my brake pads changed and ever since then when I brake it makes a loud sound. I don't think I need brake fluid.

Comment: Hi Ann and welcome.   Have you asked the mechanic who changed the pads?
( and Why The First Caps?  Makes It Hard To Read!   )

Comment: A crude, fast , simple check is to feel the temperature of each wheel as soon as you stop. A dragging brake will warm the disc/drum and then the wheel . Any wheel that is warmer than the others would indicate a problem .

Answer (score 1):

Jack up the truck and rotate the tires. If they didn't turn freely, you need to fix the brake.